# Jack/earpiece detection in iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, ipad

Anyone could tell me how to detect when a jack of an earpiece is plugged-in into an ipad or iphone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can call AudioSessionGetProperty and then get the value "kAudioSessionProperty_AudioInputAvailable" to detect whether an audio jack has been plugged in.

I.e.

```
AudioSessionInitilize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
UInt32 propertySize, micConnected;
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioInputAvailable, &propertySize, &micConnected);
```

Comment: Well, i'm not an apple programmer but you'd want to call it when you need to check.

For example, if you need to "wait" for an input device then you could display a screen waiting for it and call the AudioSessionGetProperty method in a loop with a timer (not sure what it is in x-code)